# A transparent, flexible, custom bordered and cornered box with a gradient to top it off. I've been working for hours and not getting far

Tags: css

9 images:

- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box-tl.png
- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box-t.png
- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box-tr.png
- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box-l.png
- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box-m.png
- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box-r.png
- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box-bl.png
- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box-b.png
- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box-br.png

Final product:

- http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/images/box.png

All images contain transparency so overlapping won't work. I'm so stuck, if anyone could even point me in the right direction I'd be so grateful.

Comment: You could just do this with CSS3 and skip all the image stuff, is that an option?

Comment: Afraid not. Needs to work on IE8 +, and look exactly how the designer has mocked up in the last image.

Comment: Do you care about elegance or do you just want anything that works?

Comment: At this stage in the game anything that works will be fine. I can always go back and do it more gracefully but I need to meet a deadline.

Comment: http://www.consciouslight.co.uk/shop2/ - the box on the left. My code so far. I gave up on elegance and semantic markup long ago.

Comment: There we go... I've updated my post and it works better now... had to upload a new image though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda sorta not really.  It's incredibly messy but this can do

http://jsfiddle.net/33SHY/2

Comment: This is 100 times better than what I have. Upvoted but not solved. Will give you a tick if I can get it working from this. Thanks!

Comment: Posted comment on the wrong answer earlier.. :/ Well.. This is the way to go +1

Comment: Hmm, problem is that the content needs to be in the class="t" div, because the gradient needs to be behind the content. But if you put the content in t, because it's absolutely positioned, there's nothing to push the box down to its full height.

Comment: @LeonAves actually... I think I can make this better... sec

Comment: This explains what i mean.. i hope: http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/4051/unled1tpi.jpg

Answer (score 1):

> Note that these are both done with slightly different image slices. i
>   included 'blueprint' at the bottom.

### Works ie8+ ( html+css )

Since i kinda said something about the middle part in my comment that i later realized was of course wrong because theres shadows.. i figured i would make example of this.

Ive never done this with images like this and with `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` so, i quickly realized that there would be problems in some versions of IE.

Works ie8+ ( works ie7+ IF you set both height and and width values to the wrapping element Or the content element content element might be safer... idk.. )

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhzP4/

---

### Works ie7+ ( html+css+js )

Here's a jquery fix for ie7.. cause.. IMO ie7 is the minimun requirement.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhzP4/5/ ( `.CornerWrap` still has width set to it in the css but its not necessary.. )

changed this into the js:

```
$('.CornerWrap').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.Height').css({ height:$(this).find('.BoxContent').height() });
    $(this).find('.BoxContent').css({ width: $(this).find('.BoxContent').width() });
});
```

and added extra padding div cause IE was giving me hard time getting the Real height consistently with the padding in the element.

> FYI - Zooming in or out is not cool with this as the width and height
>   attributes are static..

---

### Jibberish ( ..bla..bla..blah.. )

I'd also like to add that 'normally' if it wasnt a box that has gradient happening.. you could just repeat the sides no problem.. Though one way to go about it would be to use css3 to stretch the bg image rather than repeating it since it doesnt work with gradient...

Though i did now get an idea that you could basically add more divs all freaking over and then add transparent gradients there... but.. easier way is easier.

---

Slice 'blueprint' for *gradient* box. Each box shape represents a different image.

```
+--+-----+--+
|  |     |  | <-- css background's
+--+-----+--+
|  |     |  |
|  |     |  |
|  |     |  | <-- <img>'s
|  |     |  |
|  |     |  |
+--+-----+--+
|  |     |  | <-- css background's
+--+-----+--+
```

Answer (score -1):

I've come up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nc6rR/2/

there should be png with transparency at the bottom and top